# Conditional or Absolute Convergence or Divergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence {$f_n$} is defined recursively by $f_1=1$, $f_2=1$ and $f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$, for all $n \ge 3$. Define the sequence {$r_n$} of ratios by setting $r_n=\frac {f_{n+1}}{f_n}$, $n \ge 1$.
a) Use the definition of the sequence {$f_n$} to give a recursive definition of the sequence {$r_n$}.

For this question I found that 
$r_n=\frac {f_{n}+f_{n-1}}{f_n}$
 $r_n=\frac {f_n}{f_n}$ + $\frac {f_{n-1}}{f_n}$
 
$r_n=1 + \frac {1}{f_n/f_{n-1}}$
$r_n=1 + \frac {1}{r_{n-1}}$

b) It is known that the sequence {$r_n$} converges. Find its limit R.
Since the sequence converges $R=\lim_{x \to \infty} r_n= \lim_{x \to \infty} r_{n-1}$.

So I found that that,
$R= 1 + \frac {1} {R}$
Then $0= R^2-R-1$
$R= \frac {1+\sqrt5}{2}$

But, I am having trouble solving part c which asks,

c)Use part (b) to determine whether the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {1}{f_n}$ converges conditionally, converges absolutely, or diverges

I assume that you have to use either the ratio or root tests, but I don't know how to do that or what equation to use for this question.

Comment: Let $a_n = \frac{1}{f_n}$. Notice you already computed $\lim\sup\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$ in part (b). Using the ratio test, bound $\lim\sup\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ appropriately to conclude something about the convergence of the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the ratio test, you need to compute
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{f_{n+1}}}{\frac{1}{f_n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_n}{f_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n} $$
Since the series consists of positive terms only, convergence implies absolute convergence as well.